# How to check if a Javascript Class inherits another (without creating an obj)?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

Eg:

```
function A(){}
function B(){}
B.prototype = new A();
```

How can I check if the class B inherits class A?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
ChildClass.prototype instanceof ParentClass
```

Comment: What about **ES6** `class` ? `class A extends B{}` then how can I check the inheritances of class `A`

Comment: @Omid **ES6 class syntax** is mostly just that: some special _syntax_. Behind the scenes the actual handling of "classes" hasn't changed and thus you can still work with `A.prototype` ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 46):

You can test direct inheritance with

```js
B.prototype.constructor === A
```

To test indirect inheritance, you may use:

```js
B.prototype instanceof A
```

*(this second solution was first given by Nirvana Tikku)*

Comment: No that will only check the parent class, not all the heritage chain.

Comment: Just restored it. Thanks dystroy (for updating this answer, too)

Answer (score 29):

back to 2017:
check if that work for you

```js
ParentClass.isPrototypeOf(ChildClass)
```

Alternative if you want protection against shadowing:

```js
const isPrototypeOf = Function.call.bind(Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf);

// Usage:
isPrototypeOf(ParentClass, ChildClass); // true or false
```

Comment: Works perfectly but lint complains.  It seems that if the program does not have complete control over ParentClass, then there is a risk of ParentClass faking the answer.  It extends to all prototype functions.  If the program does have complete control over ParentClass then should be no problem.

Comment: How it can fake the answer? by using Symbols ? and why should they do that, if it happens it probably by design

Comment: "Additionally, objects can have properties that shadow the builtins on Object.prototype, potentially causing unintended behavior or denial-of-service security vulnerabilities."

Comment: "For example, it would be unsafe for a webserver to parse JSON input from a client and call hasOwnProperty directly on the resulting object, because a malicious client could send a JSON value like {"hasOwnProperty": 1} and cause the server to crash.
To avoid subtle bugs like this, it's better to always call these methods from Object.prototype. For example, foo.hasOwnProperty("bar") should be replaced with Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, "bar")."  -- https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins

Comment: I disagree that it must ALWAYS be replaced.  Only necessary when, in this case, the programmer doesn't control the range of possible ParentClass values.

Comment: Just mention, if it parsed from JSON stream there is no prototype related because it's just data, not Class.btw, JSON can't pass functions just Array, Object, and Primitive.
 But I learned to take your caution into account. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  Lint could make an exception for `isPrototypeOf`, but doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

**Gotchas:** Note that `instanceof` does not work as expected if you use multiple execution contexts/windows. See [§§](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof#instanceof_and_multiple_context_(e.g._frames_or_windows)).

---

Also, per https://johnresig.com/blog/objectgetprototypeof/, this is an alternative implementation that is identical to `instanceof`:

```
function f(_, C) { // instanceof Polyfill
  while (_ != null) {
    if (_ == C.prototype)
      return true;
    _ = _.__proto__;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Modifying it to check the class directly gives us:

```
function f(ChildClass, ParentClass) {
  _ = ChildClass.prototype;
  while (_ != null) {
    if (_ == C.prototype)
      return true;
    _ = _.__proto__;
  }
  return false;
}
```

---

**Sidenote**

`instanceof` itself checks if `obj.proto` is `f.prototype`, thus:

```
function A(){};
A.prototype = Array.prototype;
[]instanceof Array // true
```

and:

```
function A(){}
_ = new A();
// then change prototype:
A.prototype = [];
/*false:*/ _ instanceof A
// then change back:
A.prototype = _.__proto__
_ instanceof A //true
```

and:

```
function A(){}; function B(){};
B.prototype=Object.prototype;
/*true:*/ new A()instanceof B
```

If it's not equal, proto is swapped with proto of proto in the check, then proto of proto of proto,  and so on. Thus:

```
function A(){}; _ = new A()
_.__proto__.__proto__ = Array.prototype
g instanceof Array //true
```

and:

```
function A(){}
A.prototype.__proto__ = Array.prototype
g instanceof Array //true
```

and:

```
f=()=>{};
f.prototype=Element.prototype
document.documentElement instanceof f //true
document.documentElement.__proto__.__proto__=[];
document.documentElement instanceof f //false
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29543030/632951 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/30993434/632951

Comment: in your modified code snippet you have 'C.prototype', though have you have replaced the 'C' parameter with 'ParentClass'

Answer (score 1):

It differs between class (B) and class instance (b) ...

```
function A(){}
function B(){}
B.prototype = new A();
const b = new B();

console.log(B.prototype instanceof A);
// true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(b) instanceof A);
// true
```

Similarly

```
class E extends Error {}
const e = new E();

console.log(E.prototype instanceof Error);
// true
console.log(e.constructor.prototype instanceof Error);
// true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(e) instanceof Error);
// true
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think Simon meant `B.prototype = new A()` in his question, because this is certainly not the way to chain prototypes in JavaScript.

Assuming B extends A, use `Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf.call(A.prototype, B.prototype)`

Comment: I think you have the best answer for today, but `B.prototype = new A()` was indeed a valid way to chain prototypes (for those wanting classical-style inheritance) at least before `class` was introduced in ES6.

Answer (score 0):

None of all others didn't work for me. ChatGPT couldn't too. I've solved by the following code.

```
/**
 * Checks whether a given object is inherited from a specified superclass.
 * 
 * @param {Object} object - The object to check.
 * @param {Function} superClass - The superclass to compare against.
 * @returns {boolean} - True if the object is a subclass of the superclass, false otherwise.
 */
isInheritedFrom(object, superClass) {
    console.log(`Checking if ${object.constructor.name} is a subclass of ${superClass.name}`);
    
    let currentProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(object.constructor);

    while (currentProto) {
        if (currentProto.name === superClass.name) {
            console.log(`Found match for a superclass of ${object.constructor.name} with ${superClass.name}`);
            // object is a subclass of the superclass
            return true;
        }
        currentProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(currentProto);
    }
    
    console.log(`No match found for ${object.constructor.name} with ${superClass.name}`);
    // object is not a subclass of the superclass
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).