# How does instanceof work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In the following code sample both checks of obj2 and obj3 at the end with *instanceof* return true even if the ways there were constructed are different and the results of returning *name* property are different.

```
var Obj1 = function() {
    this.name = "foo1";
};
Obj1.prototype.name = "foo1onProt";
var obj1 = new Obj1();

var Obj2 = function() {};
Obj2.prototype = new Obj1();
Obj2.prototype.constructor = Obj2;
var obj2 = new Obj2();

var Obj3 = function() {};
Obj3.prototype = Object.create(Obj1.prototype);
Obj3.prototype.constructor = Obj3;
var obj3 = new Obj3();

console.dir(obj1);
console.log("obj1.name: " + obj1.name);

console.dir(obj2);
console.log("obj2.name: " + obj2.name);

console.dir(obj3);
console.log("obj3.name: " + obj3.name);

console.log("obj2 instanceof Obj1: " + (obj2 instanceof Obj1));
console.log("obj3 instanceof Obj1: " + (obj3 instanceof Obj1));
```

Result of the run in Chrome:

```
Obj1
  name: "foo1"
  __proto__: Object
    constructor: function () {
    name: "foo1onProt"
    __proto__: Object
obj1.name: foo1
Obj2
  __proto__: Obj1
    constructor: function () {}
    name: "foo1"
    __proto__: Object
      constructor: function () {
      name: "foo1onProt"
      __proto__: Object
obj2.name: foo1
Obj3
   __proto__: Object
   constructor: function () {}
   __proto__: Object
     constructor: function () {
     name: "foo1onProt"
     __proto__: Object
obj3.name: foo1onProt

obj2 instanceof Obj1: true
obj3 instanceof Obj1: true
```

What is the best way to recognize that *obj2* and *obj3* are different?
How does actually *instanceof* work?

Comment: You create two different objects, both with Obj1 as their base - and then you ask them if they are instances of Obj1. Well, yes, they both are. If you want to know if they are different, then just use the `===` operator.

Comment: @AHM I see your reply is from many years ago, however I have never seen an approach using strict equality to directly compare JavaScript objects. Would you mind expanding on what you meant by your comment above regarding ‘objA === objB‘ ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality#comparing_objects

Comment: For objects, the === operator returns true only if the two objects compared are the same object. While you would not normally compare an object to itself, this can be useful if you want to figure out which of object, out of a known set, you have a reference to.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> What is the best way to recognize that obj2 and obj3 are different?

That will depend a great deal on what you're doing with them. One way would be to use `instanceof Obj2` and `instanceof Obj3`. Since both objects were created with `Obj1.prototype` in their prototype chain, it makes sense that they identify as being an instance of what we would call the supertype in class-based OOP.

> How does actually instanceof work?

### The short version

`obj instanceof F` looks to see if the object referenced by `F.prototype` is anywhere in `obj`'s prototype chain. It doesn't use `constructor` at all.

### More details

This is covered in the spec by [§11.8.5 - *The instanceof Operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.6), which says (indirectly, via [§8.6.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2)) that it calls the `[[HasInstance]]` internal method of the function object, passing in the object we're testing. `Function`'s `[[HasInstance]]` (in [§15.3.5.3](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.5.3)) says that it gets the object reference from the function's `prototype` property and then returns `true` if that object is anywhere in the target object's prototype chain, `false` if it doesn't.

It doesn't use `constructor` (nothing in JavaScript itself does, in fact) — and if you think about it, it can't, because an object's `constructor` property can only point at one function, but an object can be `instanceof` multiple functions — for instance, in the case of pseudo-classical inheritance:

```js
function F1() {}

function F2() {
  F1.call(this);
}
F2.prototype = Object.create(F1.prototype);
F2.prototype.constructor = F2;

var obj = new F2();
console.log(obj instanceof F1); // true
console.log(obj instanceof F2); // true
```

Both are true because the two objects referenced by `F1.prototype` and `F2.prototype` are both in `obj`'s prototype chain.

`instanceof` being true doesn't necessarily mean that `obj` was created by a call to `F`, either directly or indirectly; it just indicates there's a vague link between them (`F.prototype` refers to an object that's also in `obj`'s prototype chain). It *usually* means `F` was involved in creating the object, but there's no guarantee.

For instance:

```js
function F() {}
var obj = Object.create(F.prototype);
console.log(obj instanceof F); // true
```

Note that `F` wasn't called to create the object, at all.

---

Or perhaps more clearly and/or dramatically:

```js
function F() {}
var p = {};
var obj = Object.create(p);
console.log(obj instanceof F); // false
F.prototype = p;
console.log(obj instanceof F); // true
```

---

There's also this unusual, but entirely possible, version:

```js
function F1() {}
function F2() {}
F1.prototype = F2.prototype = {};
var obj = new F1();
console.log(obj instanceof F2); // true
```

---

Or this one:

```js
function F1() {}
function F2() {}
var obj = new F2();
console.log(obj instanceof F1); // false
F1.prototype = F2.prototype;
console.log(obj instanceof F1); // true
```

Comment: @VLAZ - Thanks, I didn't know any of my answers still used that. I'll have to go hunting...

Comment: oh, right...I also meant to write a comment to notify you. I forgot about that during editing. :) Also, I tried finding the repo but seems it's gone, I assume because it's not needed any more.

Comment: @VLAZ - No need to leave a comment, SO notifies you when your answer is edited. :-) I don't recall removing that repo, but it seems more likely that I did than that github lost it. :-D Ugh, data explorer says I have 349 of these to fix... ;-( At two minutes per, that's nearly 12 hours of work. I'll do 5-10 a day for a month or two...

Comment: Maybe you can [automate it](https://xkcd.com/1319/) :) I can also lend a hand every once in a while. I've recently taken to updating some older posts mostly with making snippets runnable. I'm still exploring ways to find which posts to update, I'm mostly browsing and reviewing entire Q&As that catch my eye. So, it's unguided and sporadic for now - your posts give a more direct goal I can work towards.

Comment: @VLAZ - That's very kind! I can do it in dribs and drabs, but if you want to pitch in, [here's the list](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IpQb0h4WH1uSMHmnQ8Qyyo5y_hXeX1KEK28QH6FvCI0/edit?usp=sharing), just change any you do to strikethrough text (please don't delete them). If you see any with my old-style ASCII-art using - instead of  −, could you add a note? I'll go fix them. :-) But again, **only** if you really want to, I'll get to them otherwise. (I've already done a few that aren't on that list, so it's not 349 anymore...)

Answer (score 3):

Most simply: `obj instanceof constructor` yields `true` when `obj` has `constructor`'s prototype in it's constructor/prototype chain. In other words, your asking your engine whether `obj` can be treated like an instance of `constructor` / whether `obj` behaves like a `constructor` object.

There is a small handful of syntaxes that allow you to put `constructor`'s prototype in `obj`'s prototype chain. Any and all of them will cause `obj instanceof constructor` to be `true`. In your examples, both `obj2` and `obj3` have `Obj1` in their prototype chain.

So, when you ask your javascript engine whether *either* `obj2` or `obj3` behave like an instance of `Obj1`, JavaScript assumes `true` -- the only case wherein they wouldn't is if you've overridden `Obj1`'s behavior down the line.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Good distinction.

Comment: This is wrong answer. The answer of T.J. Crowder is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```rs
function F1() {}

function F2() {
  F1.call(this);
}
F2.prototype = Object.create(F1.prototype);
F2.prototype.constructor = F2;

var obj = new F2();
console.log(obj instanceof F1); // true
console.log(obj instanceof F2); // true
```