# How instanceof is implemented in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Lets consider the following code snippet:

```
function A() {}
var obj = new A();
function B() {};
obj.constructor = B;
console.info("1: ", obj.constructor); //Function B
console.info("2: ", obj instanceof A); //true
console.info("3: ", obj instanceof B); //false
```

My guess to decide if and object is an instance of some function class or not, the JS engine must be checking if the object has the same constructor property or not. But it does not seem happening so, as even overriding the constructor property of an object does not alter it's instanceof output.

Comment: You're looking for the spec.

Comment: For fun, run the code you just talked about in your Chrome console or similar. You'll notice that `obj` has a `__proto__` method that is still called `A`. I don't really know the answer to your question, but I think it would have something to do with that. It's something deeper than just JavaScript.

Comment: Couple of duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+does+instanceof+work

Comment: @FelixKling yes the question is duplicate, my bad, I tried deleting the question but couldn't... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) states:

> The instanceof operator tests presence of constructor.prototype in
>   object's prototype chain.

Answer (score 3):

The ECMAScript 262 specification will tell you this. Quoting directly from its [*The `instanceof operator*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.6) section:

> ## [11.8.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.6) The instanceof operator
>
> The production RelationalExpression : RelationalExpression instanceof ShiftExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating RelationalExpression.
> 2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> 3. Let rref be the result of evaluating ShiftExpression.
> 4. Let rval be GetValue(rref).
> 5. If Type(rval) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
> 6. If rval does not have a [[HasInstance]] internal method, throw a TypeError exception.
> 7. Return the result of calling the [[HasInstance]] internal method of rval with argument lval.

As for what `[[HasInstance]]` is, the specification also defines that in its [*Object Internal Properties and Methods*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) section as:

> #### [[HasInstance]]
>
> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the argument is likely an Object that was constructed by this object. Of the standard built-in ECMAScript objects, only Function objects implement [[HasInstance]]

Further reading on this: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5.3

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the way I see it is that I've already linked to the specification, twice now. If we're to continue to then quote from [this section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5.3) you could then argue that I'd also need to say what `[[TargetFunction]]` is, and it'd just go on and on forever.

Comment: Your call. All the above basically says is that "`instanceof` will call the `[[HasInstance]]` internal method (on the function object)" where the bit in parentheses is only if you can read spec-speak. That's a pretty far cry from explaining what it **does** (in my view, not speaking for others). Not that the links aren't great.

Answer (score 1):

*(I've now answered the question identified as the previous question this is a duplicate of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29543030/157247), and so have marked this CW. That answer is basically just a copy of this one, generalized a bit.)*

---

### The short version

`obj instanceof A` looks to see if the object referenced by `A.prototype` is anywhere in `obj`'s prototype chain. It doesn't use `constructor` at all.

### More details

This is covered in the spec by [§11.8.5 - *The instanceof Operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.6), which says (indirectly, via [§8.6.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2)) that it calls the `[[HasInstance]]` internal method of the function object, passing in the object we're testing. `Function`'s `[[HasInstance]]` (in [§15.3.5.3](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.5.3)) says that it gets the object reference from the function's `prototype` property and then returns `true` if that object is anywhere in the target object's prototype chain, `false` if it doesn't.

It doesn't use `constructor` (nothing in JavaScript itself does, in fact) — and if you think about it, it can't, because an object's `constructor` property can only point at one function, but an object can be `instanceof` multiple functions — for instance, in the case of pseudo-classical inheritance:

```js
function A() {}

function B() {
  A.call(this);
}
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;

var obj = new B();
snippet.log(obj instanceof A); // true
snippet.log(obj instanceof B); // true
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Both are true because the two objects referenced by `A.prototype` and `B.prototype` are both in `obj`'s prototype chain.

`instanceof` being true doesn't necessarily mean that `obj` was created by a call to `A`, either directly or indirectly; it just indicates there's a vague link between them (`A.prototype` refers to an object that's also in `obj`'s prototype chain). It *usually* means `A` was involved in creating the object, but there's no guarantee.

For instance:

```js
function A() {}
var obj = Object.create(A.prototype);
snippet.log(obj instanceof A); // true
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Note that `A` wasn't called to create the object, at all.

---

Or perhaps more clearly and/or dramatically:

```js
function A() {}
var p = {};
var obj = Object.create(p);
snippet.log(obj instanceof A); // false
A.prototype = p;
snippet.log(obj instanceof A); // true
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

There's also this unusual, but entirely possible, version:

```js
function A() {}
function B() {}
A.prototype = B.prototype = {};
var obj = new A();
snippet.log(obj instanceof B); // true
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

Or this one:

```js
function A() {}
function B() {}
var obj = new B();
snippet.log(obj instanceof A); // false
A.prototype = B.prototype;
snippet.log(obj instanceof A); // true
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```