# How are these two Java Script codes different?

Tags: javascript

In second code  "Bird.prototype and Dog.prototype is not instance of Animal"

Why is so? No such problem in first code.

```js
    //First
    function Animal() { }
    function Bird() { }
    function Dog() { }
    
    Bird.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
    Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
    
    // Only changes  in code below this line
    Bird.prototype.constructor=Bird;
    Dog.prototype.constructor=Dog;
    
    let duck = new Bird();
    let beagle = new Dog();
```

```js
    //Second
    function Animal() { }
    function Bird() { }
    function Dog() { }
    
    Bird.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
    Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
    
    // Only change code below this line
    Bird.prototype={constructor:Bird};
    Dog.prototype={constructor:Dog};
    
    let duck = new Bird();
    let beagle = new Dog();
```

Comment: `instanceof` does not depend on `constructor`, but rather "prototype chain", which is apparently broken by the second approach. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453301/how-does-instanceof-work-in-javascript) for more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example you **modify** the object assigned to `prototype`.

In the second example you **replace** it.

```js
const thing = { a: "value" };

const a = {};
const b = {};

a.example = Object.create(thing);
b.example = Object.create(thing);

a.example.b = "other";
b.example = { different: "object" };

console.log( { a, b } );
```