# Check if a constructor inherits another in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototypal-inheritance

I have a situation where I need to check if a constructor (X) has another constructor (Y) in its prototype chain (or is Y itself).

The quickest means to do this might be `(new X()) instanceof Y`. That isn't an option in this case because the constructors in question may throw if instantiated without valid arguments.

The next approach I've considered is this:

```
const doesInherit = (A, B) => {
  while (A) {
    if (A === B) return true;
    A = Object.getPrototypeOf(A);
  }

  return false;
}
```

That works, but I can't shake the sense that I'm missing some more straightforward way to check this. Is there one?

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(A) instanceof B` should work I think.

Comment: That's what I'm using above (but with ==), and it does work (though it needs to be looped over, because the inheritance is not always direct). Or maybe I misunderstand?

Comment: No, my point is to use  `Object.getPrototypeOf(A) instanceof B` instead of looping. You are doing something completely different :P

Comment: Yeah, I realized what you meant after I re-read it, but I just tried it and it doesn't work. `getPrototypeOf` doesn't return an instance, it returns the constructor.

Comment: Oh wait. `A` and `B` are constructors. Then just do `A.prototype instanceof B`.

Comment: Ah! Well, that's it, thanks (in the form `(X == Y) || (X.prototype instanceof Y)`). Want to put it in an answer?

Comment: Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45656957/632951

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Because of the way `instanceof` works, you should be able to do

```
A.prototype instanceof B
```

But this would only test inheritance, you should have to compare `A === B` to test for self-reference:

```
A === B || A.prototype instanceof B
```

[Babel example](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code=class%20A%20%7B%7D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%7D%0Aclass%20C%20extends%20B%20%7B%7D%0Aconsole.log%28C%20%3D%3D%3D%20C%29%0Aconsole.log%28C.prototype%20instanceof%20B%29%0Aconsole.log%28C.prototype%20instanceof%20A%29):

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B {}

console.log(C === C) // true
console.log(C.prototype instanceof B) // true
console.log(C.prototype instanceof A) // true
```

---

`instanceof` is basically implemented as follows:

```
function instanceof(obj, Constr) {
  var proto;
  while ((proto = Object.getProtoypeOf(obj)) {
    if (proto === Constr.prototype) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

It iterates over the prototype chain of the object and checks whether any of the prototypes equals the constructors `prototype` property.

So almost like what you were doing, but internally.

Comment: Thanks. The `instanceof` logic is good to know, too. I was forgetting that a constructor's prototype property would itself be an instance of the super constructor -- must be all that `class` sugar getting to me, just as people feared :>

Comment: You accidentally put two opening parenthesis `while ((proto...`

Comment: @Fahmi: that was intentionally, to indicate that I really want an assignment to happen here and not a comparison (i.e. it indicates that `=` is not a typo).

Comment: @FelixKling So you're missing another closing parenthesis then? :P

Comment: @Fahmi: I guess I do :D

Answer (score 15):

There's also [`Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf). Seems like a perfect use case, no?

[Babel](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20A%20%7B%7D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%7D%0Aclass%20C%20extends%20B%20%7B%7D%0Aconsole.log(C%20%3D%3D%3D%20C)%0Aconsole.log(B.isPrototypeOf(C))%0Aconsole.log(A.isPrototypeOf(C))&playground=false)

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B {}
console.log(C === C)
console.log(B.isPrototypeOf(C))
console.log(A.isPrototypeOf(C))
```

Comment: Wow, yeah, that's great. This is exactly what I was envisioning, but I must have missed it while trawling MDN. I wish I could accept both answers, but I'm gonna leave the green check with Felix because it's also correct and thorough.

Comment: Why have I never used the function even though it exists since ES3??

Comment: No idea, but it definitely flies under the radar. When I first read up on it I thought it was something future-spec - one of those ES6 *'Look what we forgot to put into the language until now'* types of methods.

Comment: I should probably dedicate some time to reading over all the built-ins since every so often one of these turns up. My question seems kind of dumb in retrospect given how simple the answers turned out to be (my first -1 :/ I think) but I'm still glad I asked.

Comment: @FelixKling: Because until ES6 classes, constructors did not inherit from their super class constructors :-)

Comment: @Bergi: true, but that method could still have been useful. I guess I'm just shocked and ashamed that I didn't know about it :-/

Comment: *isPrototypeOf* and *instanceof* fail across global contexts, such as iFrames, so are unreliable (hence why `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)` is used instead of `obj instanceof`). Feature testing is more effective, particularly when ECMAScript tends to encourage generic methods that work with different types of object. You may not have known about it because you just didn't need it. ;-)

Comment: @Oka, Hmm, surprising that they came up with Yet Another Funciton. Isn't this redundant? How is this different from `instanceof`?

Answer (score 3):

BEWARE:  The above answer of checking ES6 classes A, B, C inheritance-chain with isPrototypeOf() works great. But it doesn't work like you might expect for pre-ES6 classes Object, Array, Function etc.

```
 Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf (Array.prototype); // => true
```

But:

```
 Object.isPrototypeOf (Array);   // => false
```

This is like it should be. INSTANCES of Array inherit the methods of Object.prototype. But the "class" Array does NOT inherit the "class" Object. If you add a method to Object you can not call it via Array. Array does not inherit methods of Object (if any). It's just that user-created classes work differently!

Perhaps we should not think of Object and Array and Function as "classes" at all - even though you can create instances of them. They are only "constructors". Or we can say that they are classes but that built-in classes in JavaScript work differently from user-created ones.