# Get all classes/constructors by given @decorators

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi all I am wonder if that is possible get all classes that have given decorator javascript/typescript.

I have class for example

```
@mydecorator
class SomeClass1{
}
```

and somewere else in module

```
@mydecorator
class SomeClass2{
}
```

then in other module in runtime i would like to get all classes or constructors that have decorator @mydecorator ... I am afraid that this is not possible :(

```
export function getaAllClassesByDecorator(decorator:string){
... return constructor or something that  i am able to call static method 
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you need them for?

Comment: I was look for elegant way how to globally register class and than create. Something like dependency pattern.

Comment: Doesn't the ES6 module system already give you that?

Comment: Yes, but i am developing mobile web i was looking for some general hamburger menu for each view. So my idea is add label PATH to each view/component  than in hamburger menu component get all classes with attribute Path and generate menu tree structure.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618212/find-all-classes-in-a-javascript-application-that-extend-a-base-class/68470454#68470454

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to "register" all classes that uses @mydecorator somewhere. This register logic should be implemented in @mydecorator. For example:

```
export const registeredClasses = [];
export function mydecorator() {
     return function(target: Function) {
          registeredClasses.push(target);
     };
}

@mydecorator()
class SomeClass1{
}

@mydecorator()
class SomeClass2{
}
```

Now you can get all registered classes in the **registeredClasses** array

Comment: This approach is what i am looking for ... if that will work ... you made my day!  Tomorrow i am going to check it :-) thx

Comment: take a look on my repos on github there are more complex examples how to use decorators

Comment: Will that work? If the classes decorated by this decorator are never referenced directly they will not be registered, because the decorators will never be executed. Am I wrong?

Comment: @BrightShadow I am going through this right now and I think I am in the safe boat. The decorator function is not triggering if the classes are in separate modules. In which case I have to import the classes with side effects only at which point we might use plain old registration.
I guess I was looking to implement a Java Spring like setup with decorators.

Comment: not work if  the class not  be  called .

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that "automatically", but you can create a registry with said classes.
Then inside your decorator function you add these classes:

```
const REGISTRY: { [name: string]: any } = {};

function mydecorator(constructor) {
    REGISTRY[constructor.name] = constructor;
}
```

Then you can query this `REGISTRY` and know who used this decorator.