# Getting the name of a class on which a static function has been called

Tags: javascript

So my question is as follows: Can I get the name of a class on which a function got called? To illustrate that problem I will give a short code example.

```js
class Base {
    static getClassName() {
        // get the caller class here
    }
}

class Extended extends Base { }

Base.getClassName(); // Base
Extended.getClassName(); // Extended
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this, or say if this is even possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all classes in a Javascript application that extend a base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618212/find-all-classes-in-a-javascript-application-that-extend-a-base-class)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sorry, but it doesn't make much sense, does it? When you write `Base.getClassName()` you already know it should be `Base`, right? In other words, the moment you write your code you already know the name of the class because otherwise you wouldn't be able to write the line.

Comment: @David you are absolutely right, but passing the name of a class to the function is just annoying if I do it 100 times and I thought it could be easier

Comment: @Koflin OK, I get it now. Thanks. I was just wondering :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code should work:

```js
class Base {
  static getClassName() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

class Extended extends Base {}

console.log(Base.getClassName()); // Base
console.log(Extended.getClassName()); // Extended
```

In a static method, `this` refers to the class object itself.

Comment: `Base.name` works also, and is way simpler. I'd rather use `getClassName` for a non-static method of obtaining the class of an instance at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, functions have a read-only `name` field ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)). Since classes are functions, you can simply use `MyClass.name` to statically get the class name.

To get the class name of functions at runtime, reference the `Function.name` of the constructor function.

```js
class Base {
  getClassName() {
    return this.constructor.name;
  }
}
class Extended extends Base {}
console.log(Base.name);
console.log(Extended.name);

const base = new Base();
console.log(base.getClassName());
const extended = new Extended();
console.log(extended.getClassName());
```

Comment: yeah but if I don't have an instance of Extended is this.constructor.name still working?

Comment: strange how the console.log gives me "Function"