# Get child class name

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to get class name that extends the class?

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(){
    console.log(extendedBy.name);//extendedBy.name to be replaced with "Bar"
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
}
```

I tried using Google and Stack but only found how to get the parent (I.E. Foo) name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking to do something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618212/find-all-classes-in-a-javascript-application-that-extend-a-base-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [this.constructor.name](https://dmitripavlutin.com/understanding-constructor-property/#4-get-the-class-name) :

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(){
    console.log('Foo extendedBy : ', this.constructor.name);
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
}

class OtherBar extends Foo {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
}

class ByBar extends Bar {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
}

const MyBar = new Bar();
const MyOtherBar = new OtherBar();
const FromBar = new ByBar();
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't found this before

Comment: Better yet, use `new.target.name`