# Get all the classes that extend a main class

Tags: node.js, class, oop

So, if I had something like

```js
class Event {// . . .}

class Children extends Event {// . . .}

class Second extends Event {// . . .}
```

Would there be any way to retrieve the `Children` and `Second` class objects, using the the parent class `Event`?

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) where you are asking questions about a possible solution to some other problem without telling us what that other real problem is.  We could probably help you better with the real problem since this possible solution is a dead-end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all classes in a Javascript application that extend a base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618212/find-all-classes-in-a-javascript-application-that-extend-a-base-class)

Answer (score 1):

> Would there be any way to retrieve the Children and Second class objects, using the parent class Event?

No.  Given just the code you show, there would not be any way to identify all subclasses of `Event` in plain Javascript.  A parent object is not informed in any way when a subclass is defined, nor is any global catalog maintained.  A subclass definition stands on its own and the fact that it subclasses/extends the `Event` class is not saved anywhere or registered anywhere.  It's just information that is used when an instance of the subclass is actually created.

If you wanted to manually keep track of such a thing, you could create your own catalog of sub-classes and then make your code register everything in that catalog.

Comment: @rayhutera - Did this answer your question?