# Check if the constructor call is coming from extended class

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

Suppose we have two libraries:

1. A library written by someone, using the `function` and `prototype` syntax to build class-like types in JS.
2. A library we write, using ES6, extending the first library.

Using `class OurLibrary extends TheOtherLibrary {...}` works fine (even `TheOtherLibrary` is declared using `function TheOtherLibrary (...) {...}` and its methods are appended using the `prototype` way).

The problem is that when not using classes, you can `return` values. A common way is to handle calls without `new`. That's the problem I'm running into now.

We have something like this:

```
function TheOtherLibrary (foo) {
  if (this.constructor !== TheOtherLibrary) {
     return new TheOtherLibrary(foo);
  }
  //...
}
TheOtherLibrary.someMethod = function () {/*...*/};

class MyLibrary extends TheOtherLibrary {
   constructor (foo) {
       super(foo);
   }
   anotherMethod () {/*...*/}
}

var bar = new MyLibrary(42);
console.log(bar.constructor.name);
// => TheOtherLibrary
console.log(bar.anotherMethod);
// => undefined
```

So, how to improve the if expression from the second line to check if the call is coming from an extended class?

```
var notCalledFromExtendedClass = ???
if (this.constructor !== TheOtherLibrary && !notCalledFromExtendedClass) {
   return new TheOtherLibrary(foo);
}
```

Or is there a hope to get this working in another *better* way?

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45656957/632951

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) like this to detect whether `TheOtherLibrary` is anywhere in the prototype chain:

```
function TheOtherLibrary (foo) {
  if (!(this instanceof TheOtherLibrary)) {
     return new TheOtherLibrary(foo);
  }
  ...
}
```

This will work for a direct instance of `TheOtherLibrary` or for an instance of any derived class.  If you want to support calling without `new` for the derived classes too, then you have to put this structure in the constructor for the derived classes too so you catch whatever constructor function is being called without `foo` and can then create the right type of object.

Comment: Oh, awesome! Thanks a lot! Didn't know it's so simple. :-) Happy new year!

Comment: @jfriend00, Is there a way to get specifically the .constructor of .constructor?

Comment: @Pacerier - What is a constructor of a constructor?  You can typically (though not always) get the constructor for an object instance with `obj.constructor`, but that isn't a constructor of a constructor so I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @jfriend00, From the instance `bar`, how do we get a ref to the instance `MyLibrary`? (`bar.constructor` and `bar.__proto__.constructor` doesn't work.)

Comment: If the whole object definition is done appropriately, it will work.  You'd have to show exactly what code you're using.  I'd suggest you post a new question since that's a different issue than this question.  For example: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/x5k8kgqs/.

Comment: @jfriend00, I'm referring to the exact code as shown in the question. From the `bar` instance, is there any way to get a reference to `MyLibrary`?

Comment: @Pacerier - Did you look at the jsFiddle in my previous comment. It's all there.  Two ways to do it.  Continued comments on a topic that is NOT related to this question or answer is really not a proper usage of stack overflow.  If you're still confused after the help I've already given, then please post your own question.