# Check if class type extends another class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, instanceof, typeof

I'm having a hard time to express my problem, take this following code for exemple.

```
class Foo {}

class Bar extends Foo {}

const myFct = (bar: typeof Bar) => {
    if(bar instanceof Foo) { 
        // I want to check if Bar extends Foo 
        // bar is not an instance so instanceof won't do it
    }

}
```

How I can check the class Bar extends Foo from a typeof ?

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf`?

Comment: does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486110/how-to-check-if-a-javascript-class-inherits-another-without-creating-an-obj/52745163

Comment: @JafarJabr  that's it , thanks !

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(Bar) === Foo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
class Foo {}

class Bar extends Foo {}

const myFct = (bar: typeof Bar) => {
    if(bar.prototype instanceof Foo) { 
        // I want to check if Bar extends Foo 
        // bar is not an instance so instanceof won't do it
    }

}
```